# Couters tag deletion

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The [couters](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/couters) tag seems to be a mis-spelled attempt at "counters". I don't think it's a good tag anyway, so I've removed it from the [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/26705/3610), [couters](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/couters) probably needs to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags which are not used by any question are removed automatically anyway, no need to really do anything about it. If I remember correctly, it takes a day for them to be removed.

Comment: Ok, I was just confused that it was still there after removing it.